# Is there some type of coating I can use to prevent condensate on my HVAC ducts?

Tags: hvac, ducts, condensation

I'm getting a lot of condensate on my HVAC ducts that run though my first floor (and HVAC blower) especially in July / August when humidity levels are outrageous (in NJ).  The 1st floor space space is rather frigid as one face of it is below grade so it's hard to convince the occupants to open the registers to dry it out (at least not without opening the windows and letting the humid air back in). However even on days when humidity is lower, I can occasionally notice a small amount of condensate build up which has clearly led to mold growth under the previous owners care. Further compounding things is the natural tendency for the cold air to make its way back down to the ground floor via the small gaps near return / air filter area and in the registers themselves.

I know most people say to just insulate it, but the previous owner did this in a few places (with neoprene peel-n-stick in some places, and standard batt in others) and it looks terrible, and it appears with standard batt insulation just provides another surface for mold to grow on.

**Is there any sort of water repelling coating that that I could use to prevent the condensate from building up in the first place the way RainX works on car windows?**

**Is there some other trick I should be using to reduce humidity or condensate build up on the duct work?**

Comment: Are you talking about interior ducts, not ducts running through unconditioned space like an attic or crawl space?  If you were in Florida, I would understand condensation.  But your profile indicates you're in Boston.  If you run the A/C and keep the house at a comfortable humidity, there shouldn't be enough moisture in the air to condense on the ducts.  But to your question, there are hydrophobic coatings that are available as a spray.  Water won't stick to it.  But if moisture is going to condense it would drip off onto whatever is below it.

Comment: coat the pipes with paraffin; it's the same stuff they use in rainX (along with mineral spirits to liquefy) and should force droplets to slide down much faster than nature provides.

Comment: @dandavis, I'm not sure getting the condensate to drip more quickly is going to solve the overall dampness problem -- it's just likely to transplant the location where the mold grows.

Comment: @virtualxtc: i though the question was "how to stop it building up?", but you're right; it only displaces it. Still, it might be easier to collect or wick from underneath. There's a rainX anti-fog too; not sure what it uses, but it might be of use as well. I would try wrapping a few layers of cloth around the pipe; if you insulate it (thermally) enough, it won't fall under the dew point, and thus won't get wet.

Comment: rainX is paraffin; a traditional waterproofing that's been used for centuries on all manner of materials. I for one find it useful on toilet seats to avoid surprises. reduces shower and sink maintenance as well.

Comment: You don't have a condensation problem. You have a humidity level problem. Don't treat the symptom--run a dehumidifier. Even if you insulate your ducts, your humidity level is so high that you're sure to have other issues.

Comment: You might try increasing airflow by running the fan at a higher speed to reduce the temperature differential. I'm in Minnesota, where we regularly see temps in the upper 90s with dew points in the 70s. The issue you describe isn't a problem for most of us and shouldn't be for you.

Comment: Yep, we're all talking about dew points in the low to mid 70s. There's nothing special about Florida humidity. The physics of it is the same.

Comment: @isherwood, "There's nothing special about Florida humidity."  Sounds like you've never spent time in Florida.  :-)  Sure, it's the same physics, but the high exterior humidity and temperature cause interior problems that you don't normally run into up north.  But I agree with the rest of your comments.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My contractor started installing a soffit before I was ready, so I ended up using expanding foam as a way to insulate isolate my ducts and shaved it to size before it was fully enclosed. It worked, but I'd advise against using regular spray foam (like I did) as it will expand and cause your ducting to shift out of place.

If you go this route, choose the window foam variety which is designed to be "minimal-expanding" as to avoid warping and shifting your ducts (both polyurethane and the latex varieties should work).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Alternatively, you might try a 'no sweat' kind of product I found while previously researching this, but why this answer is currently ranked at -1 as I couldn't find any studies or reviews of how well they work:

[image: Anti-Sweat Spray Insulation 18 Oz. Aerosol Can]

[image: This Franklin Machine Products 143-1128 No Sweat Cold Pipe Insulation Spray]

[image]

Comment: One thing to keep in mind. Whatever "coating" or treatment you use for this is going to be outgassing or otherwise getting into the air stream and people will be breathing it continuously. Remember, people used to line air ducts with asbestos and that lead to a lot of sickness and death (a friend of mine died from that after working in a state office building for 20+ years). You may find that these treatments will not be qualified for that kind of application. Read the MSDS (Material Safety Data Sheets) on it before you buy anything.

Comment: @J.Raefield good point, however, according to the manufacturer of the last product, it's [supposedly 'food grade' safe](http://hvac-talk.com/vbb/showthread.php?1788701-Anti-condensation-coatings)

Answer (score 1):

I call it “The Coke bottle” effect. When you take a coke bottle out of refrigerator, it sweats on the WARM side.

The same thing happens when you start pumping cold air through your metal ducts in a warm atmosphere. (And vice versa for warm air.)

Paint doesn’t isolate the metal duct surface so you’ll have condensation.

I’d look to “duct insulation” which is made specifically for ducts. Some are self-sealing and have a peel and stick adhesive so it would be easy to apply.

Comment: I agree there is a thin neoprene self adhesive sheet that is amazing at eliminating this problem but it is over 5x the cost of fiberglass duct wrap. The trick is keeping the warm moist air away from the duct, if sealed up with insulation there won't be any moisture to grow mold.

Comment: I've been researching this all night as I'm in the middle of a reno which is giving me access to the top side of the ducts that is too close to the ceiling to normally paint.  Someone in a forum recommended spray foam over the peel-n-stick stuff as it will completely seal and provides a better R-value, however, I can't figure out how I'd apply it evenly, or get it to form into a shape.